# How to create JSON data with custom structure in a custom structure in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular, typescript

**USE CASE:** I need to create JSON data with the following structure dynamically from the formData in ANgular.

Required JSON Structure

```
{
        "variables": {
            "phone": {
                "value": "1234567890",
                "type": "String"
            },
            "email": {
                "value": "9876543210",
                "type": "String"
            }
        }
    }
```

So far I have managed to create like this.

```
    {
    "variables": {
        "phone": {
            "value": "1234567890",
            "type": "String"
        }
    }
}
```

With this code:

```
    this.parametres = {};
    var element = {};
    Object.keys(this.sampleForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key + " -- " + this.sampleForm.get(key).value);

        element = {
            [key]: {
                "value": this.sampleForm.value[key],
                "type": "String"
            },
        }
    });

    this.parametres = {
        variables: {
            ...element
        }
    }
```

How can I add more elements inside variables:{} like the required JSON structure?

I tried creating element as an array but that leaves index numbers inside the parameter.

Comment: you are overriding the `element`. try updating it.
like `element[key] = ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of forEach you can use `reduce` method like that

```
const parameters = Object.keys(this.sampleForm.value).reduce((prev,curr)=>{
   prev[curr] = { 
      value: this.sampleForm.value[curr],
      type: typeof this.sampleForm.value[curr] // not sure about that.
    }
   return prev;
}, {})
```

Comment: Yes. This works too. Had to tweak a little bit. Wrapped it inside variables:{ ...parameters}

Comment: Is there any BIG DIFFERENCE in using reduce instead of forEach?

Comment: forEach will just loop over elements, reduce give you the ability to merge the result of each iteration and return the merged result. But it still depends on your usage.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the info